# How to send checkbox value to selected row

Tags: mysql, forms, codeigniter, checkbox, row

I have problem sending data from my **answer** value from *checkbox* to selected row in  database

I am using pagination also.

Here is my Controller:

```
function index() {
        $this->load->library('pagination'); // pagination setting start from here
        $config['base_url'] = site_url('dcm/index');
        $config['per_page'] = 6;
        $config['num_link'] = 5;
        $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
        $config['prev_link'] = 'Prev' ;
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('soal')->num_rows();

        /* here we are the main problem */
        $data['form_action'] = site_url('dcm/index'); 
        $jawab = $this->input->post('jawab');       //<-- $jawab AS answer, this variable grab answer  
        $id_soal = $this->input->post('id_soal');   //<--  $id_soal AS ID, this variable just for posting ID
        $this->dcm_model->inputJawab(); // <-- for sending data to Model 

        /* pagination */
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['query'] = $this->db->get('soal', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
        $data['link'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->load->view('dcm/soal', $data); }
```

This my Model code:

```
function inputJawab(){
    $data   = array();
    if($this->input->post('jawab')){
        $jawab    = $this->input->post('jawab');
        foreach($jawab as $each){
            if(isset($each) && $each != ""){
                $data['jawab'] = "1"; 
                $this->db->where('id_soal', $each)->update('soal', $data); 
            } // 'soal' is my table name
        } // 'id_soal' is my column name AS id
    } // 'jawab' is my column name AS answer
}
```

This is my view code:

```
<form action="<?php echo $form_action; ?>" method="post">
<?php echo $link; ?> <!-- <-- for pagination link -->
<!-- HERE WE ARE -->
<?php  foreach($query->result() as $row) { ?>
<span> <?php echo $row->id_soal . '. ' . $row->soal; ?></span>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"  value="1<?=$row->id_soal?>" name="jawab[]" />
<input align='center' type='submit' value='SELESAI' />
```

Here is my database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `soal` (                                      
      `id_soal` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,               
      `id_bagian` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,                        
      `soal` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,                        
      `jawab` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,                             
      PRIMARY KEY (`id_soal`)                                  
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=232 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: what really your problem is? you can't send it to the view?

Comment: @LeonardDrapeza not, my problem is, my checkbox in view cannot send value to my database

Comment: but do you receive the POST'ed data in your model when send?

Comment: You have 1<?=$row->id_soal?> as the value of your checkbox so if id_soal was something like 5 the checkbox value would be 15 which will never be right in your where statement.